# Is there any API available to get how many slots of specific browser available in selenium grid?

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I would like to get the number of tests running with a specific browser in the selenium grid.

I have looked at the existing API, where i can get the slotcount which is the sum of all the available slots which includes all the browsers.

ex: `curl -X GET http://localhost:4444/grid/api/hub/ -d '{"configuration":["slotCounts"]}'`

Output will be: `{"success":true,"slotCounts":{"free":178,"total":196}}`

**Is there any API available to get how many slots of chrome browser(say) available?**

Other options come to my mind is to parse the existing API

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:4444/grid/console
```

which return the full stack, where i need to parse the html structure, which is like

```
<img src='/grid/resources/org/openqa/grid/images/chrome.png' width='16' height='16' class='busy'  title='POST - /session/8802ebae-10cb-480d-bbbd-5e7edd7ee7b2/execute executed.'  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Currently there's no such API available out there in the Selenium Grid that can do this for you.

You would need to build a custom servlet which when invoked can extract and provide this information for you.

Your Hub servlet could look like this:

```
import org.openqa.grid.internal.ProxySet;
import org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry;
import org.openqa.grid.internal.RemoteProxy;
import org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.RegistryBasedServlet;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleServlet extends RegistryBasedServlet {
    public SimpleServlet(Registry registry) {
        super(registry);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ProxySet proxySet = getRegistry().getAllProxies();
        Iterator<RemoteProxy> iterator = proxySet.iterator();
        Map<String, List<String>> returnValue = new HashMap<>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            RemoteProxy each = iterator.next();
            each.getTestSlots().forEach(slot -> {
                String browser = (String) slot.getCapabilities().get(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME);
                String machineIp = each.getRemoteHost().getHost();
                List<String> machines = returnValue.get(browser);
                if (machines == null) {
                    machines = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                machines.add(machineIp);
                returnValue.put(browser, machines);
            });
        }
        //Write logic to have the Map returned back as perhaps a JSON payload
    }
}
```

You can refer to the Selenium documentation [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#customizing-the-grid) to learn how to inject servlets to the Hub or the node.

Comment: Thanks @Krishnan, Currently we have created an API to get this info which returns something like this `{"AvailableFirefox":84,"TotalFirefox":84,"AvailableChrome":84,"TotalChrome":84,"AvailableInternetExplorer":28,"TotalInternetExplorer":28}` I will check this in with creating it as servlet soon